# How to import SequelizeDatabaseError

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to write a test that asserts that a `SequelizeDatabaseError` is thrown. How can I require `SequelizeDatabaseError`?

This doesn't work:

```
const { SequelizeDatabaseError } = require('sequelize');
```

I'm using sequelize v4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in your models:

```
import db from "./models"

console.log(db.Sequelize.DatabaseError);
```

Comment: Thanks. The name `SequelizeDatabaseError` vs `DatabaseError` confused me.